# Why does ncurses fail when I reload a dynamic library?

Tags: c, ncurses, linux-mint

I've been following along with this blog post on "[Interactive Programming in C](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/23/)". The general ideal behind it is that it displays an implementation of Conway's Game of Life in `ncurses`, but the game logic is loaded as a dynamic library. The `main()` loop monitors the `.so` for the game and reloads it interactively if it finds a newer version.

I've tried this in LinuxMint 17, but `ncurses` hangs when the shared library is dynamically reloaded. I've put in some debug `fprintf`s and followed the program execution in GDB, and the program seems to reload the library correctly and continue the main loop as usual.

It seems that `ncurses` is the problem here, but I've no idea how to debug it. The `ncurses` function `refresh()` in `game.c:draw()` starts returning -1 once the dynamic library is reloaded. Can anyone help? The code can be found in the [github repo](https://github.com/skeeto/interactive-c-demo) linked in the blog post.

#### Update

It looks like the variable `stdscr` in the `ncurses` library just disappears after the call to `dlclose()`. This doesn't happen on my RedHat machine at work.

Comment: Do you have `libncurses5-dbg` installed?

Comment: @elliot-frish - I do now. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still learning about all this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ncurses is a dependency of your `libgame.so`, not of the `main` executable. So if you unload the dynamic library and load the changed version, you also unload ncurses and then load it again. But you then fail to reinitialize it. That is why your program fails.

The proper solution is to call `endwin()` in `game_unload` to cleanup ncurses's state and then reinitialize it in `game_reload`:

```
static void game_reload(struct game_state *state)
{
    initscr();
    raw();
    timeout(0);
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
}

static void game_unload(struct game_state *state)
{
    endwin();
}
```

Another solution would be to force the linker to link ncurses against the main executable. This will prevent the dynamic linker from unloading it when you unload the game library. You can do that by adding the `-Wl,--no-as-needed` flag before the `$(LDLIBS)` variable when you compile the `main` executable:

```
main : main.c game.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Wl,--no-as-needed $(LDLIBS)
```

If you prefer this solution, consider to also move the ncurses initialization/cleanup to the `main.c` file. There is no technical reason for this, it's merely a matter of clean coding style.

Comment: And to add to that, the Red Hat installation of the OP is probably sufficiently old enough that the `--no-as-needed` linker flag was the default unlike newer toolchains, where `--as-needed` is the default.

Comment: Thanks Phillip (and nos). I think I don't need `-Wl,--no-as-needed` if I just include the `ncurses` headed in `main.c` and move the setup and destroy for `ncurses` into `main()` (removing it from `game.c)?

Comment: Indeed. Since `main` requires symbols from ncurses then, the linker won't remove the dependency on its own.